# HAML Twitter Bootstrap Tabs Doesn't Work Properly Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am having trouble with twitter bootstrap tabs in (HAML) ruby on rails. The tabs are showing up but the content doesn't change when I click on the respective tabs. The statements below are also showing up at the bottom of tab1 contents on the web page.
-Howdy, I'm in Updates.
-Howdy, I'm in Sponsors.
-Howdy, I'm in Comments.

The code below shows where the tab content is listed.

Thanks for your help!

```
    .row#main-content{style:"background-color: white;margin-bottom:40px;"}
        .span8#content-left
            .tabbable
                %ul.nav.nav-tabs
                    %li.active
                        = link_to "About", "#tab1", "data-toggle"=>"tab"
                    %li
                        = link_to "Updates", "#tab2", "data-toggle"=>"tab"
                    %li
                        = link_to "Backerss", "#tab3", "data-toggle"=>"tab"
                    %li
                        = link_to "Comments", "#tab4", "data-toggle"=>"tab"

                .tab-content
                    .tab-pane.active{id: "tab1"}            

                        .row-fluid#content-left-first-row
                            = image_tag("content1.png")

                        .row-fluid#content-left-second-row
                            .span5
                                %button.btn#btn-like
                                    %i.icon-thumbs-up
                                    Like
                                %span{style: "font-size:80%;"} 976 people like this.Be the first of your friends.                           
                            .span2
                                %button.btn#btn-tweet
                                    %i.icon-twitter                         
                                    Tweet
                            .span5
                                %button.btn.btn-small#btn-embed <>Embed

                                %input{type:"text", placeholder:"http://loremipsum", style:"width:150px;margin-bottom: 0px;"}
                        .row.hr-row
                            %hr.hr-row
                        .row-fluid#content-left-third-row
                            %p
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                %br
                                %br
                                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                %br
                                %br
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.
                            = image_tag("content2.png")             
                            %p
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                %br
                                %br
                                Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                %br
                                %br
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.
                                %br
                                %br
                                Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        .row-fluid#content-left-fourth-row
                            %h4{style:"margin-top: 50px;"} Have a question?
                            .row.hr-row
                                %hr.hr-row
                            .span9{style:"margin-left: 0px;"}
                                %p
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                            .span3
                                %button.btn.btn-primary.btn-large.pull-right{style:"margin-top: 20px;"} Ask a Question

                .tab-pane{id: "tab2"}
                    %p Howdy, I'm in Campaigns.
                .tab-pane{id: "tab3"}
                    %p Howdy, I'm in Campaigns Donations.
                .tab-pane{id: "tab4"}
                    %p Howdy, I'm in Personal Donations.
```

Comment: Is the indentation right? As I can see .tab-pane classed divs not on same level in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the tabs to work the `.tab-pane` should be at the same level which is not in your case.

See [documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs).

You need to have a markup like this

```
.tab-content
  #tab1.tab-pane.active
    //content for #tab1 goes here. 
  #tab2.tab-pane 
    //content for #tab2 goes here. 
  #tab3.tab-pane 
    //content for #tab3 goes here. 
  #tab4.tab-pane 
    //content for #tab4 goes here.
```

In your code above

```
.tab-content
  .tab-pane.active{ :id: "tab1"}
    = image_tag("content1.png")

.row-fluid#content-left-second-row
```

`.row-fluid#content-left-second-row` is out of tab-content and also the rest of the content. Hence the tabs is not working as tab-content has only one `.tab-pane`.

You need to shift all the code between `.tab-pane#tab1` and `.tab-pane#tab2` inside tab1.

Like this

```
.tab-content
  .tab-pane.active{ :id => "tab1"}
    = image_tag("content1.png")

    .row-fluid#content-left-second-row
      ...
    .row.hr-row
      %hr.hr-row
    .row-fluid#content-left-third-row
       ...    
    .row-fluid#content-left-fourth-row
       ...
  .tab-pane{:id =>  "tab2"}
    %p Howdy, I'm in Updates.
  .tab-pane{:id =>  "tab3"}
    %p Howdy, I'm in Sponsors.
  .tab-pane{:id =>  "tab4"}
    %p Howdy, I'm in Comments.
```

Comment: I'm new to Ruby on Rails so I'm still not able to fix the problem. I updated my code above to reflect the changes.

Comment: I have updated the code above. The id `id : "tab1"` should be `:id => "tab1"`. Also inspect and see if the elements are inside the correct parents if not then the indentation is wrong. You should get a markup [like this](http://troll.ws/image/0a1bc709)

Comment: By following your example, I finally got it to work. The code wasn't indented properly. Thanks